# How to save data in Android

Tags: android, save

I have done some research and I see there are several ways to store data from an android app and I am not sure which I should use.

I am looking to save 2 files, one with a lot of int (1500 - 2000) and the other with a lot of strings (588).

Both need to be read by the app when it starts but not again unless the app is closed.

The really important requirement is that the files can be removed from the app and put on another device. The idea being if the used has a tablet and a phone they can set up the app on the phone and then copy the files to the tablet.

What would be the best method of saving my data considering its type and the requirements ?

Comment: Is [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) giving you any problems?

Comment: @323go I read that page, its what left me confused and made me ask this question

Comment: Your question might be more useful if you explained which part of that got you confused. As is, you're just asking folks to restate readily available documentation, which leads to the poor answers you see below.

Comment: JSON/XML/CSV formarts would be a good solution

Answer (score -1):

If you clear the App data from Application Manager, all shared preferences data will be deleted.
That's why you should not use Shared Preferences.

Answer (score -1):

The best way for you is to save data in text file so that you can use that in multiple devices. Code to save data in file:

```
        try {
            File sdCard=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File myFile = new File(sdCard,"filename.txt");
            myFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                    new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            String data="your data";
            myOutWriter.append(data);
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Add this to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```